# How to eliminate overlapping date ranges in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to eliminate overlapping date ranges in the data set. A smaller data set that I will be used:

[image]

How would I eliminate the highlighted first row of data as it overlaps the other date ranges for that specific id?

Comment: Look into ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...)

Comment: You should provide data schema and try something by yourself.

Comment: I have tried several things by myself, but cannot get anything to work properly.

Comment: How does it overlap compared to row 6 & 7? The Begin Time is earlier than any row for that ID.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Welcome to SO.  You need to show the community your efforts first.  In this case even the select you used to get the data in the image would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

This is provided as a basic way to get you started since you are new to SO. You will undoubtedly need to change the logic on what you classify as overlapping.

```
--your test data...
declare @table table (ID int, BeginTime datetime, EndTime datetime)
insert into @table (ID, BeginTime, EndTime) VALUES
(101,'7/4/2016','9/21/2016'),
(101,'8/8/2016','9/8/2016'),
(101,'9/8/2016','9/21/2016'),
(102,'9/2/2016','9/7/2016'),
(103,'9/22/2016','9/28/2016'),
(103,'9/23/2016','9/28/2016')

/*
In SQL 2012 onward use LEAD and LAG to compare rows to the ones above or below them

Change this logic as you need... based on the limited information for "overlapping" 
I just placed a flag where the dates didn't light up perfectly. There are undoubtedly
more cases / better logic you will need.
*/

select 
    ID,
    BeginTime,
    EndTime,
    case when lead(BeginTime) over (partition by ID order by BeginTime asc) <> EndTime then 'n' else 'y' end as toKeep
from @table


--This is the same logic applied in a CTE so we can update the table

;with cte as(
    select 
        ID,
        BeginTime,
        EndTime,
        case when lead(BeginTime) over (partition by ID order by BeginTime asc) <> EndTime then 'n' else 'y' end as toKeep
    from @table)

--Update your table via the CTE

delete from cte where toKeep = 'n'
select * from @table
```